# few Azure questions

Tags: azure

I am working with Azure to deploy my MVC3 application. Few things want to ask.

1 - Do I need to republish my whole project to azure if I make some changes in the code. if not than how to upload changes.?

2 - Are there any charges when we publish our project to azure like charges for data used to upload.?

3 - If I select instance count to 2 in VS2010 by right click roles property will I be charge extra for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pirzada, to answer your questions: 1) Yes, every time you make a change to the code, you'll need to recreate your Windows Azure service package, redeploy it to the staging environment in Windows Azure and then do a virtual IP swap (or VIP Swap) to make your changes live in production. You can check out [How to Swap a Services's VIPs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee517253.aspx) for more information on that. 2) No, you will not be charged for the upload to the Management portal. 3) The Windows Azure billing is done on a per hour per instance basis, and so yes, you'll be charged for each instance that is deployed for your solution. I suggest checking out the article [Application Life Cycle Management for Windows Azure Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff803362.aspx) to get a better idea of how to make changes to an application that has previously been deployed to Windows Azure. You should also check out [How to Perform In-Place Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee517255.aspx) for more information about upgrade a production application.

Comment: Is there a way to publish to azure even if there is 1 error during compilation which is due to 3rd party DLL and won't effect application?

Comment: If it's in the package, and you need to change it, the only way to do it is to create a new package and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jonathan says, you can now use the [Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Roles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/07/12/now-available-windows-azure-accelerator-for-web-roles.aspx) which enables you to publish using Web Deploy, a much quicker process for small changes.